# PHP XPATH Mind Melt

Tags: php, xpath

Really simple xpath call but I am having a mindblock.

My XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book>bob</book>
</books>
```

I want do an XPATH call to find the node with the value of bob whcih seems to work but whenever I put a no exsistent book value in, it still returns the node of bob. My XPATH Query is

```
/books/book[.='bob2']
```

Is my XPATH wrong? Really having a mad brain block!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

you can just select `/books/book` and test for equality to "bob2". alternatively, you can use the text() function, but with [some caveats](http://www.xquery.com/tips_and_tricks/using_text_in_XPath.html).